# Sequential logit model in sports

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, logistic

Validated users, hi all!

Is there some research that uses sequential logit models (or similar) to study the effect of X on the probability to win match Nth of the series.

[X could be anything, I am just interested in the methodology and its application. If the application comes from the sports field is better; however, if there are similar applications from politics, transportations or else, it would be ok. I give more details below]

Imagine NBA playoffs, where two teams play against each other in a series made of 7 matches.
I figure that this model could be used because the probability to win match Nth in the series depends on the probability of having won match Nth-1 in the same series (e.g. if one of the two teams win the first 3 matches in a series of 5 matches, these two teams won't play the 4th and 5th match).

Something to give me a head start.

I have used this model only once, to study entrepreneurship phases (e.g. the initial idea of opening a business -> the planning of opening a business -> opening a business -> running the business, etc...)

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question sounds like a variant of the "hot hands" phenomenon in sports. Lots of literature on that, Andrew Gelman being among the more prominent exponents. https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2020/02/08/the-hot-hand-fallacy-fallacy-rears-its-ugly-ugly-head/  https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2014/08/12/understanding-hot-hand-myth-hot-hand-time/

Comment: thanks! this is a couple of interesting articles